# Is a proxy required to use OpenLayer's GetFeatureInfo?

Tags: openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, proxy

My domain is hosted on HostGator and apparently they don't allow the use of proxies.

I have a map that has a WMS point feature hosted from my GeoServer using OpenLayers.

I want to be able to select a point and get information from it.

Can I do this without using a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GetFeatureInfo without proxy, when both your OpenLayers application and GeoServer live in same domain and same port. If they are in different location, you need proxy. Simple as that.